# CSS two level menu - second level doesn't appear in proper position

Tags: css, menu

I have the menu using css. The second level menu pops out right one levwl below the actual menu item hover. In the below example, i want the second level appear in line to "Keyboard Entry" menu item. I have attached the html file.

CSS:

```
#navbar {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 1.8em;
   background-color: #5e8ce9;
   }
#navbar li {
   list-style: none;
   float: left;

    }
#navbar li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    background-color: #5e8ce9;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navbar li ul {
   display: none; 
   width: 10em; /* Width to help Opera out */
   background-color: #69f;}



#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0; }
#navbar li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {
   float: none; }
#navbar li:hover li a, #navbar li.hover li a {
   background-color: #69f;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
   color: #000; }
#navbar li li a:hover {
   background-color: #8db3ff; }




#navbar li:hover ul li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul li.hover ul
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 100%;
    top:1;
}


#navbar li:hover ul ul, #nav li.sfhover ul ul {
    left: -999em;
}

#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li li:hover ul, #navbar li.sfhover ul, #navbar li li.sfhover ul {
    left: auto;
}
```

MY HTML:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">File</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Match</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">View</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Data</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Import Carbon CSV Files</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Rework Carbon Components</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Keyboard Entry</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Orifice Data Entry</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Leaflets Data Entry</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Rings Data Entry</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>            
            <li><a href="#">Specifications</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Matched Components</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Audit Reports</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Admin</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Security</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ewolik/1/edit
Simple dropdown Menu:
http://jsbin.com/ewolik/2/edit

1. Position the first level of Li elements relative:

   ```
   #navbar li {
       list-style: none;
       float: left;
       position:relative;

   }
   ```
2. Position the second level ul with absolutely with an top offset equal to the first level lis height:

   ```
   #navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0; 
       top:1.8em;
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi Shadow, it didn't work as expected. when i tried to mouse over the first level menu , it just disappears. my question is only on the second level as i couldn't get same level right to it's parent menu item.

Comment: when i just mouse over the drop down menu, it just disappears. sam ebehavious on your link as well. Are you able to navigate Keyboard entry -> orifice entry menu?

Comment: Try this http://jsbin.com/ewolik/2/edit it works, you just need to add your links and color. There seem to be some improperly nested elements in your demo and weird unnecessary css which is causing issues.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: whats the problem? Second menu appears as you hover over first level menu? See this jsbin.com/ewolik/2/edit

Comment: Sorry. I meant third level to be displayed inline right to second menu list on mouse hover.